# Display and style column total in table footer

Tags: jquery, css, html, datatables

I am trying to color code a row in table and I am able to do it if I keep sorting disabled .

**JavaScript:**

```
 $(function () {

    $('#example2').DataTable({
      "ajax": "../json/daily_status.json",
      "fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex ) {            
        if ( iDisplayIndex == 9 ) {
            $('td', nRow).each(function(){
                           $(this).html( '<td bgcolor="#BE81F7"><b>'+$(this).text()+'</b><td>' );
                        });
        }
        return nRow;
    },
      "scrollX": false,
      "ordering": true,
      "paging": false,
      "info": false,          
      "searching": false,
       dom: 'Bfrtip',
       buttons: [
            'excel'
            ]         
    });
  });
```

**HTML:**

```
<table id="example2" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                   <th>STATUS_CODE</th>
                   <th>Count</th>                       
                  </tr>
                </thead>
       </table>
```

JSON Data :--

```
{"data":[["Authorized","4847"],["Pending Authorization","670"],["Pending Acceptance","344"],["Pending Audit","314"],["Pending First Approval","248"],["Pending Second Approval","208"],["In Progress","82"],["Ready for Audit","22"],["Pending Resolution","8"],["Total","6743"]]}
```

But as soon as I enable the sorting multiple rows gets color coded . This is happening as I am passing table row  for color coding.

Is there any way to send the value instead of row ? I want only the row where 1st column value is **Total** to be colored.

[image]

Comment: Would you consider using [Footer callback](http://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/footer_callback.html) instead? In your example, when table is sorted **Total** row will move, but in the example I mentioned it will always stay at the bottom.

Comment: I tried that option but it keeps failing  at .reduce( function (a, b)  for total pages. I am not sure how  to use it only for one page .

Comment: Can you post response from `../json/daily_status.json` in JSON format?

Comment: Updated the JSON value in main

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **SOLUTION**

Consider using [`footerCallback`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/footerCallback) to display total in the table footer instead, see [Footer callback example](http://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/footer_callback.html). That way it will not be affected by sorting and you can apply any CSS rule to `tfoot` element.

```js
var table = $('#example2').DataTable({
   "ajax": "../json/daily_status.json",
   "scrollX": false,
   "ordering": true,
   "paging": false,
   "info": false,          
   "searching": false,
   "footerCallback": function ( row, data, start, end, display ) {
        var api = this.api(), data;

        // Remove the formatting to get integer data for summation
        var intVal = function ( i ) {
            return typeof i === 'string' ?
                i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '')*1 :
                typeof i === 'number' ?
                    i : 0;
        };

        // Total over all pages
        total = api
            .column( 1 )
            .data()
            .reduce( function (a, b) {
                return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
            }, 0 );

        // Update footer
        $( api.column( 1 ).footer() ).html(total);
    }    
});
```

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L3ypv1Lb/1/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: I keep getting error  Uncaught TypeError: Reduce of empty array with no initial value   for the line .reduce( function (a, b) {

Comment: @user2854333, can you try again? I have made minor code correction.